# Dart: lists of supertype takes subtype only at runtime

Tags: dart

I ran into an issue similar to this:

```
    void main() {
      _buildMixedList([1,2.3,4,5.6,7.6,8]);
     _buildHomogeneousList([1,2,4,5,7,8]);
    }
    
    abstract class NumberWrapper {}
    
    class DoubleWrapper extends NumberWrapper{
      final double myDouble;
      
      DoubleWrapper(this.myDouble);
    }
    
    class IntWrapper extends NumberWrapper{
      final int myInt;
      
      IntWrapper(this.myInt);
    }
    
    List<NumberWrapper?> _buildMixedList(List<dynamic> numbers) {
        List<NumberWrapper?> wrappers = numbers.map((number) {
          if(number is int){
            return IntWrapper(number);
          }
          if(number is double){
            return DoubleWrapper(number);
          }
          return null;
        }).toList();
        wrappers.add(DoubleWrapper(0.2));
        return wrappers;
      }
    
    List<NumberWrapper?> _buildHomogeneousList(List<dynamic> numbers) {
        List<NumberWrapper?> wrappers = numbers.map((number) {
          if(number is int){
            return IntWrapper(number);
          }
          return null;
        }).toList();
       wrappers.add(DoubleWrapper(0.2));
        return wrappers;
      }
```

As you can see, the two methods are doing something similar (adding object of different types to a list). The first one adds different objects inside a `map()` function and the other adds only one type in map() and then adds another after.

The second one throws this error:

```
: TypeError: Instance of 'DoubleWrapper': type 'DoubleWrapper' is not a subtype of type 'IntWrapper?'Error: TypeError: Instance of 'DoubleWrapper': type 'DoubleWrapper' is not a subtype of type 'IntWrapper?'
```

As if the list is being changed to `List<IntWrapper?>` just because we only added `IntWrapper`s in the `map()`.

I wrote this test code after encountering this in one of my projects, so it's not representative of a real case. I tried it on dartPad.

Coming from a java background I was expecting the second method to work. Is it a bug or is it intended? If intended, why is that so?

Comment: Just a tip: If you want to take both `int` and `double`, you can use the `num` type. So instead of `List<dynamic>` you can do: `List<num>`.

Comment: @julemand101 as I stated, this is not representative of a real case, I just wrote this particular code to simplify it and make it easier to understand. I actually have completely different classes of course.

Comment: Thats ok. I just hate to see the use of `dynamic` where it can be prevented :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there are a difference between the type of the variable and the type of the object which you are pointing to.

So in this case:

```
  List<NumberWrapper?> wrappers = numbers.map((number) {
    if(number is int){
      return IntWrapper(number);
    }
    return null;
  }).toList();
```

What you are actually are doing is creating a `List<IntWrapper?>` which you are using a variable of the type `List<NumberWrapper?>` to point at. Why? Because the type of the variable in this case does not change the type of the returned `List` from `toList()` (which type is determined by what type `map()` returns).

The reason the type is `List<IntWrapper?>` is because Dart are trying to be smart about automatically assigning the type. In this case, the analyzer can see you `List` will only contain `IntWrapper` or `null`.

I think the best solution here is to rewrite this part to something like this:

```
List<NumberWrapper?> _buildHomogeneousList(List<num> numbers) {
  final wrappers = <NumberWrapper?>[
    for (final number in numbers)
      if (number is int) IntWrapper(number) else null
  ];
  wrappers.add(DoubleWrapper(0.2));
  return wrappers;
}
```

By using the `[]` syntax to create the `List`, it is easier to specify the type you want the `List` to be.

Alternative, you can do this where we add the expected type to the `map` method:

```
List<NumberWrapper?> _buildHomogeneousList(List<num> numbers) {
  List<NumberWrapper?> wrappers = numbers.map<NumberWrapper?>((number) {
    if (number is int) {
      return IntWrapper(number);
    }
    return null;
  }).toList();
  wrappers.add(DoubleWrapper(0.2));
  return wrappers;
}
```

Comment: I see, I didn't consider that `map()` would be smart enought to take the "lowest" type basically at compilation time.